# How to build Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, makefile

I'm trying to build Bootstrap from source.  It is throwing the following error while I'm trying to run the `make` command.

```
Running JSHint on javascript...             â Done
/bin/sh: 1: recess: not found
make: *** [build] Error 127
```

This is what I've done so far

1. Clone the bootstrap repository `git clone git://github.com/twitter/bootstrap.git`
2. Install npm `apt-get intall npm`
3. Install less `npm install -g less`
4. Install jshint `npm install -g jshint`
5. Install make `apt-get install make`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing [recess](http://twitter.github.com/recess/), wrapper for less keeping CSS code clean due to the Twitter's [code guide](https://github.com/mdo/code-guide).

Just follow the instruction in the [README.md](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/README.md) file from the Bootstrap sources. See "Developers" [section](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/README.md#developers) (same info also in official [Bootstrap site](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/extend.html#compiling)):

```
npm install recess connect uglify-js jshint -g
```